# $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, with $\Delta=b^2-4ac$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, with $\Delta=b^2-4ac$.

What will happen to $\Delta$ if we make this substitution: $x \to \left(\frac{\alpha x + \beta}{\delta x + \gamma}\right)$?

I checked that nothing changes if we make a translation $x \to (x+\beta)$. If we make $x \to \alpha x$ then we get $\Delta_1 = \alpha^2 \Delta$. So they give us: $x \to (\alpha x + \beta) \implies \Delta_2=\alpha^2{\Delta}$. Trying to make the whole calculation seems a bad move! Is there any way to see what happens?

Thanks!

Comment: $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ gives $\Delta_3=\Delta$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good!! I feel like some moves are still missing! Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MOST NECESSARY STEPS**

As you noticed, if we substitute $x$ for $x+c$,  $\Delta_1=\Delta$

As @ThomasAndrews pointed out in his comment, substituting $x$ for $\frac{1}{x}$ ,$\Delta_2=\Delta$.

This is because for the quadratic equation $x^2f(\frac{1}{x})=g(x)=cx^2+bx+a$, $\Delta_3=\Delta$

From the first result, we know for $g(x+c)$, $\Delta_4=\Delta$

This implies that substituting $x$ for $\frac{1}{x+c}$ ,$\Delta_5=\Delta$

Using the second result in your question, $g(\frac{bx}{a}+c)$, $ \Delta_6=\Delta \times b^2 \times a^2$

This implies that substituting $x$ for $\frac{a}{bx+ac}$ ,$ \Delta_7=\Delta \times b^2\times a^2$

You can use this results to calculate what happens when substituting  $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, which is of the form $k+\frac{l}{mx+n}$, for which $\Delta_8=(mn)^2\Delta$.

Thus $\Delta_8=c^4\times (bc-ad)^2 \Delta$

Comment: Is this helpful?

Comment: Yes! By the way something is still missing right?

Comment: @Maffred I believe I fully answered your question with my new edit. Is it satisfactory?

Comment: Yes! Why $c^4$ is not on the same side of $\Delta$? I think we invert and then multiply by $c^2$, it should be on the right side! Is that wrong?

Comment: I mean I think it's $\Delta_8=c^4(bc-ad)^2\Delta$. By the way the formula is right for $c\not= 0$, the case $c=0$ is btw trivial so ok.

Comment: @Maffred Your right of course, I edited the question.